# Will jQuery safely evaluate a JSON response to a HTTP POST?

Tags: jquery, ajax, eval, http-post

I couldn't find in the jQuery document if any of its AJAX methods SAFELY evaluates a JSON response to a $.post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `type` parameter on the [$.post](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post) function:

```
$.postJSON = function(url, data, callback) {
    $.post(url, data, callback, "json");
};
```

Comment: Haha, I copied from the exact same feature request. Great minds think alike :P

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's JSON eval is supposedly safe, and their $.getJSON method seems to work well. All you have to do is pass the "json" parameter to the $.post and it'll automatically parse the JSON. Like so:

```
$.post(url, data, callback, "json");
```